# Health insurance when relocating

Tags: usa, insurance

My family is going to relocate to the US in December (on an H1-B visa). While my next employer does provide health insurance, I will be in an employment gap of about 2-3 weeks after we enter the US, because I can only start working officially after having obtained an SSN, which takes a few weeks.

Is there a health insurance that I could purchase to cover my family during those few weeks?

As far as I know, I cannot simply purchase travel insurance in my current home country, as these products are only valid if I actually plan to return to my current place of residence.

Comment: Where are you leaving from? Have you checked with local insurers (maybe one you are using already or one that specializes in travail insurance). For example, in France, [Allianz](https://www.allianz-voyage.fr/assurances/voyages-long-sejour.html) has a whole range of insurance contracts including some that explicitly cover you after you cease to be a resident (it's called “expatriate assurance”). It can get pricy and not all of them are available for short durations.

Comment: If you new US employer has other staff who've come from overseas, perhaps the employer's HR department has faced this question previously. Ask them.